# Store the numbers of a `for` loop's output, and sum them all?

Tags: python

I want to store integers and return the sum, using `random.randint()` for random values.

The code looks like this:

```
import random

val = int(input('How many numbers?: '))

for i in range(val):
    print(random.randint(1,99))
```

I need to print the integers to the console and then sum them and return the final sum.

Example:

```
How many numbers?: 4
84
50
35
35
Final number: 204
```

I need it to work for an infinite amount of numbers too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

right now you are not keeping track of the numbers you are printing out in val.

In order to keep track and sum up all of the numbers, you need to store them in an array.

```
import random

val = int(input('How many numbers?: '))
#random number is stored as val

for i in range(val):
#this will run from 1-val
    print(random.randint(1,99))
    #these numbers are simply being printed, not stored
```

So what we could do is store the numbers, and then print them

```
sum=0
for i in range(val):
    num=(random.randint(1,99))
    sum=sum+num
    print"random number:", num
print"The total sum is:", sum
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a list to store the numbers.
Use `sum()` to add them up.
Use `join()` to print them out.

```
import random

val = int(input('How many numbers?: '))

numbers = [random.randint(1,99) for i in range(val)]
print('\n'.join(str(i) for i in numbers))
print('Final number: {}'.format(sum(numbers)))
```

Example output:

```
How many numbers?: 5
60
70
51
65
18
Final number: 264
```

You will not be able to provide a sum for an infinite series of random numbers, nor will you be able to store them.

Comment: you may need to explain this as he said "new to programming," "experimenting with python," and his username is Noobieatcode

Answer (score 0):

**This solution only covers dealing with no end point, there are good solution already for the other aspects of the question.**

There is no way to sum up an infinite amount of numbers but you can just keep generating numbers until the program receives a `KeyboardInterrupt`

```
nums = []
try:
    while True:
        nums.append(random.randint(1,99))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

total = sum(nums)
amount_finished = len(nums)
```

Or to support a potential but not necessary limit you can use:

```
str_limit = input("enter the limit (accepts 'inf') ")
if str_limit=="inf":
    limit = float("inf")
    print ("you will need to stop the program with a KeyboardInterrupt")
else:
    limit = int(str_limit)

nums = []
try:
    while limit>0:
        nums.append(random.randint(1,99))
        limit-=1
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

total = sum(nums)
amount_finished = len(nums)
```